# Close all connection to DB in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a batch script which is running multiple scripts that scrape information and put it into a database. The scraping scripts get information and use SQL alchemy to write the information to a mysql database.

I am running into an issue. I have a try, except to run the scripts. Occasionally, some of the scripts fail, but still maintain connection to the database. This will add up, and will eventually cause a too many connections error.

Is there a way to clear all the connections to the database from the batch script? I tried "close all sessions" but it is not doing it.

Comment: How does the batch script runs multiple scripts? Spawns them as processes?

Comment: Uses runpy. IE runpy.runpath(path to the script)

Comment: We need to see how you are crating and handling these connections, otherwise it's impossible to provide useful guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Issues was that though connections were closed, the engines still remained. Calling `engine.dispose()` fixed the problem.